# Ionic or Firebase. Which auth service, and does it matter?

Tags: facebook, firebase, ionic-framework, oauth

I'm making an app using Ionic and Firebase. I plan to use Facebook Auth for it, and realized both platforms have the auth service. I'm not super keen on Auth, but I imagine I only really need one of these, and I was wondering which would be best to implement. I plan to have a database of users defined by UID in firebase, so that makes me think that Firebases Auth might work better. But then again Ionic might be easier to implement because it's all packaged according to the framework and there is a ton of very specific learning videos out there. Or maybe I'm missing something and it is required to use both. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to use [firebase-database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/) then [firebase-authentication](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/) is the best way. If you use Ionic auth service, you still have to take care of your firebase-database [authentication and authorization](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/).
So better to go with firebase...